# Trying to revive an old wordpress site, but newer versions of wordpress install a different db structure

Tags: themes, database, upgrade

I'm trying to revive a site that worked in 2015.  The theme is custom, and contains custom post types, pages, and a bunch of standard posts.

When I use Wordpress 4.4 (the version that this last worked on), the PHP in Wordpress core is too old to work (`get_magic_quotes_gpc()` has been deprecated, amongst other things, I'm sure).  When I install the current version of Wordpress, it ignores my tables, and installs the familiar Wordpress empty tables alongside them, but with `wpn3_` prefixes, instead of `wp_`, and the site behaves as a fresh install.

How do I remedy this?  Can I just rename my tables to the new prefix?  Or is there some sort of conversion process to get the old pages/metas in to the new?

Comment: How are you installing the new version? Are you following this? https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update

Comment: I wasn't, and I am now.  Now it works in my local development enviroment, but when I export the db, and upload it to my shared host, along with the new files, the production site just goes in to installing a fresh instance of Wordpress.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I was using the wrong wp-config.php, I was using one that had the new table-prefix setting.